# Not able to read the text box value

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am assigning the value to the variable from the text box on the page during the pageupload event of  AjaxFileUpload1.The problem is that, I am not getting the value from the text box to my variable even though no error throws.My variables are

```
        string scn = txtSCN.Text;
        string line1 = txtLineitem.Text;
        string aging1 = txtAging.Text;
```

Any idea why **AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete** is not able to read text box value

My cs Code is:

```
    protected void AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete(object sender,     AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
         {
   string c = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(e.FileName);
        string dpath = "~/Profile/Images/";
        string scn = txtSCN.Text;
        string line1 = txtLineitem.Text;
        string aging1 = txtAging.Text;             
        AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(MapPath(Path.Combine(dpath,c)));
        dpath = dpath + c;
        string str1 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProTracConnGMCH"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(str1);
        cn.Open();
        string sql = "Update tbNoquoteFollowupupdate set MailreceivedURL = '" + dpath + "', chkMailreceived = 1 , Buyername =  '" + buyername + "'  where scn = '" + scn + "' AND lineItem = '" + line1 + "' and Aging ='" + aging1 + "' ";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
        int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (i > 0)
        {
           // AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(Path.Combine(dpath, e.FileName));
            //AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(MapPath(dpath));
        }
        cn.Close();
        BindGridviewData1();
        cn.Open();
        string cmd2 = "Insert Into tbMulitmailsreived (scn, lineItem,followupdate, Aging,MailreceivedURL) Values ('" + scn + "', '" + line1 + "','" + DateTime.Now + "','" + aging1 + "','" + dpath + "')";
        SqlCommand sqlCommand2 = new SqlCommand(cmd2, cn);
        sqlCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cn.Close();
    }
```

Please help me

Comment: i'm going for a long shot here, isn't this cross threaded?

Answer (score 1):

I spent some time last week investigating this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21752542/cant-get-text-from-textbox-in-method-for-ajaxfileupload1-uploadcomplete) but in the end couldn't find an easy solution for this. The OP in that question solved it by storing values in the Session but for this to work you would still need to cause a postback at some stage.

There apparently was functionality planned for the AjaxFileUpload control to pass values in the Context Keys collections but this was never [implemented](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/27384). This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13080186/how-can-i-use-the-contextkeys-property-for-the-ajaxfileupload-control) describes how to implement this yourself though.

I *think* I saw another question around the same topic and the OP solved it by changing to using the [AsyncFileUpload](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx) control but I stand to be corrected...

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to add !Page.IsPostBack to your code. like this

```
protected void AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete(object sender,     AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
      string c = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(e.FileName);
      string dpath = "~/Profile/Images/";
      string scn = txtSCN.Text;
      string line1 = txtLineitem.Text;
      string aging1 = txtAging.Text;             
      AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(MapPath(Path.Combine(dpath,c)));
      dpath = dpath + c;
      string str1 =  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProTracConnGMCH"].ConnectionString;
      SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(str1);
      cn.Open();
      string sql = "Update tbNoquoteFollowupupdate set MailreceivedURL = '" + dpath + "', chkMailreceived = 1 , Buyername =  '" + buyername + "'  where scn = '" + scn + "' AND lineItem = '" + line1 + "' and Aging ='" + aging1 + "' ";
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
      int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

      if (i > 0)
      {
        // AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(Path.Combine(dpath, e.FileName));
        //AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(MapPath(dpath));
      }
      cn.Close();
      BindGridviewData1();
      cn.Open();
      string cmd2 = "Insert Into tbMulitmailsreived (scn, lineItem,followupdate,  Aging,MailreceivedURL) Values ('" + scn + "', '" + line1 + "','" + DateTime.Now + "','" +  aging1 + "','" + dpath + "')";
      SqlCommand sqlCommand2 = new SqlCommand(cmd2, cn);
      sqlCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery();
      cn.Close();
   }
}
```